# Increase margin for rate limit message when editing tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-wiki, error-message

There is a [rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295232) for submitting tag wiki edits. When you hit it, the "You can perform this action again in 30 seconds" message appears rather close to the Save edits button:

[image]

It could use a little more space, like e.g. the message you get when you don't reach the 6 character limit for regular posts:

[image]

While you're at it, it probably can use a period at the end. That's the new Stacks standard for error messages IIRC.

Comment: And its styling could be made consistent too.

Comment: *Stacks* [the design system](https://stackoverflow.design/)? *[Error messages](https://stackoverflow.design/content/examples/error-messages/)*.

Comment: Unlike other similar error messages (for example, [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy3zF.png)), there's no button to dismiss this message.

Comment: Also, the use of full stops is quite inconsistent. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUfbe.png) one has a full stop. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy3zF.png) one doesn't. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3umP.png) one does.